# How do you add the Atmel ASF to VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, atmel

I'm trying to add the Atmel ASF libraries to VSCode to program SAMD microcontrollers, but I can't figure out how. I've tried adding the ASF path to a c_cpp_properties.json file but it's not working. I've also tried adding it to the settings.json in the include and browse paths but to no avail...

I'm on MacOS Big Sur and have VSCode 1.62.0 installed.

I would have loved to just keep using Platformio but bare metal SAMD MCUs are not supported.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!